# failed to resolve dependencies. how to resolve dependency error?

Tags: grails

I am trying to integrate this plugin to my grails project.

https://grails.org/plugin/facebook-graph

I have added the dependcny in my BuildConfig file.

```
  plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.2.1"

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
        compile "org.grails.plugins:facebook-graph:0.14"
    }
```

I get the following error when i run-app.

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.0
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:facebook-graph:0.14
```

Looks like the repository was not found? How can i find the correct repository for this plugin? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Update:

My repositories are defined as follows:

```
 repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
```

Comment: post your `grails.project.dependency.resolution.repositories{}` closure

Comment: repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

Comment: update your answer, it's impossible to read as a comment...

Comment: ok i have updated my answer. thanks!

Comment: so, uncomment the `mavenRepo`s and try again

Comment: even after uncommenting the above four lines i get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109236/discussion-between-user734861-and-injecteer).

Comment: try adding `mavenRepo "https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo"`

Comment: same error. sorry that didnt help.

Comment: Try Grails 2.4.0 or above

Comment: sorry the grails version cannot be changed. it is 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

`compile ":facebook-graph:0.14"` worked for me. Get rid of `org.grails.plugins`

Comment: I still get | Loading Grails 2.2.0
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:facebook-graph:0.14